# Power shell display files in folder containing specific names

Tags: powershell

I have a list of pdf file names which i have stored in a text file line by line as shown below.

```
322223491.pdf
322223492.pdf
322223493.pdf
```

the name of the text file is `inclusions.txt`.

I am passing this to a variable:

```
$inclusion = get-content .\inclusions.txt
```

Now i want to check and display if a folder (`C:\users\xyz`) contains files passed in `$inclusions` variable how do i do that?

```
PS C:\users\xyz> Get-childitem
```

command displays the following

```
Mode      LastWritetime  Name
```

The `Name` column is the property of interest to me where in i want to compare my inclusions list and if its found in the list then i want to display them in the Powershell terminal

```
PS C:\users\xyz> Get-childitem | Select-Object -Property Name
```

is as far as i have got my head around it i dont know how to proceed further to display the filtered data by comparing it with the `$inclusions` variable.

Furthermore i want to delete the files if they match the name in the inclusions text file. So that is the final Objective to traverse through all the files in the folder compare if the name is same as in the inclusions list and if yes then delete those particular files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` to filter on a condition:

```
Get-ChildItem |Where-Object { $inclusion -contains $_.Name }
```

If you are only interested in the file names themselves, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to grab just the name of each file:

```
Get-ChildItem |Where-Object { $inclusion -contains $_.Name } |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

If you want to do something based on whether a certain folder contains one or more of the files in `$inclusion`, use an `if` statement:

```
$folderPath = "C:\users\xyz\folder\of\interest"
if(@(Get-ChildItem $folderPath |Where-Object {$inclusion -contains $_.Name}).Count -ge 1)
{
    Write-Host "Folder $folderPath contains at least one of the inclusion files"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathias. It worked like a charm. Appreciate your help :)